# New to jquery , trying to show/hide a div onclick, please advise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a hard time trying to show/hide a `div` on click. Basically you click on the flowers (`div`, the one I want to toggle) and they fade out or hide (which is good) and then disappear (which is not good). I need to be able to click on the flowers and have them fade out and then be able to click (on the same "flowers" `div`) and have them fade back in or show (like a light switch).

Here's the JavaScript code I'm using:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
$("#treeFlowers").fadeToggle()
return false;
});;
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>App 1-1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/master.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
<div id="treeFlowers">
<a href="#" class="show_hide"><img src="images/app1-1/treeFlowers.png" alt="tree Flowers"/></a>
</div>
<div id="treeApp">
<img src="images/app1-1/tree.png" alt="light tree"/>
</div>
<div id="textApp">
<img src="images/app1-1/text1.png" alt="text"/>
</div>  
<div id="flowers">
<img src="images/app1-1/flowers.png" alt="flowers" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you want your div to fade out, but still fill the space it did when it was opaque, and then toggle this behaviour on click?

Comment: but if the flowers fadeout/hide you will not be able to see them, where do you want to click again to toggle them.

Comment: Yes I want the div to fade out but as tsegay pointed out once that div fadesout/hides I wont be able to toggle fadeIn/show since that div will be hidden. Any suggestions as to what the best way is to handle that? thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest the flowers div inside another container div which will be the one being clicked on, lets call it flower-container, then do a toggle on it as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $('#flowers-container').toggle(
    function(e){ $('#threeFlowers').hide(); },
    function(e){ $('#threeFlowers').show(); });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`fadeToggle()` is an alias of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, which set `display:none;` after the opacity is brought down and `display:block;`, before opacity is brought back up. What you'll want to do is wrap your image and set the click event on the wrapper. For example:

```
<div class="flower">
   <img src="my_flower.jpg" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.flower').click(function(){
    $(this).children('img').fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<script>
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $("#treeFlowers").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Putting at the end of your document, just before the `</body>` tag ?

Also, the element with show_hide class should not be nested inside the div with treeFlowers id.